# Two Raycast causes a lag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I need your help.
I make a **Hover-car movement** script. 
Distance to ground and the Hover movement is calculated by **Raycast**,
I make **another Raycast**, because there was a **problem - hover flew too high** if you hold the button pressed.
But now **with two Raycast it cause a lag - Hover  moves in jerks.**
Interpolate does not help.

How can I make  **smooth movement without jerking**?
Please, help.

```
public class hoverController_v7 : MonoBehaviour

        Rigidbody carBody;
        float deadZone = 0.1f;

        public float hoverForce = 9.0f;     
        public float hoverHeight = 2.0f;    
        public GameObject[] hoverPoints;

        public float forwardAcceleration = 100.0f;  
        public float backwardAcceleration = 25.0f;
        public float currThrust = 0.0f;

        public float turnStrength = 10.0f;      
        public float currTurn = 0.0f;               

        public GameObject leftAirBrake;
        public GameObject rightAirBrake;

        int layerMask;


        void Start()
        {
            carBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

            layerMask = 1 <<     LayerMask.NameToLayer("Characters");
            layerMask = ~layerMask;


        }

        void OnDrawGizmos()
        {
            // сила hoverForce
            RaycastHit hit;
            for(int i = 0; i < hoverPoints.Length; i++)
            {
                var hoverPoint = hoverPoints[i];
                if(Physics.Raycast(hoverPoint.transform.position,
                                   -Vector3.up, out hit,
                                   hoverHeight,
                                   layerMask))
                {
                    Gizmos.color = Color.yellow;
                    //Color if correctly alligned
                    Gizmos.DrawLine(hoverPoint.transform.position, hit.point);
                    Gizmos.DrawSphere(hit.point, 0.5f);
                }
                else
                {
                    Gizmos.color = Color.red;
                    //Color if incorrectly alligned
                    Gizmos.DrawLine (hoverPoint.transform.position, hoverPoint.transform.position - Vector3.up * hoverHeight);
                }
            }
        }

        void Update()
        {
            // main thrust
            currThrust = 0.0f;
            float aclAxis = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
            if(aclAxis > deadZone)
            {
                currThrust = aclAxis * forwardAcceleration;
            }
            else if(aclAxis < -deadZone)
            {
                currThrust = aclAxis * backwardAcceleration;
            }

            // Turning
            currTurn = 0.0f;
            float turnAxis = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * 2;
            if(Mathf.Abs(turnAxis) > deadZone)
                currTurn = turnAxis;

        }

        void FixedUpdate()
        {
            // hover force
            RaycastHit hit;
            for(int i = 0; i < hoverPoints.Length; i++)
            {
                var hoverPoint = hoverPoints[i];
                if(Physics.Raycast(hoverPoint.transform.position, 
                                   -Vector3.up, out hit,
                                   hoverHeight, layerMask))
                    carBody.AddForceAtPosition(Vector3.up * hoverForce * (1.0f -(hit.distance / hoverHeight)), 
                                               hoverPoint.transform.position);
                else
                {
                    if(transform.position.y > hoverPoint.transform.position.y)
                        carBody.AddForceAtPosition(hoverPoint.transform.up * hoverForce, hoverPoint.transform.position);
                    else
                        //add force to car
                        carBody.AddForceAtPosition(hoverPoint.transform.up * -hoverForce, hoverPoint.transform.position);
                }
            }

            // forward
            RaycastHit hit2;
            if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -transform.up, out hit2))
            {
                if(hit2.distance < 2)
                {
                    if(Mathf.Abs(currThrust) > 0)
                    {
                        carBody.AddForce(transform.forward * currThrust);

                    }
                }
            }

            // turn
            if(currTurn > 0)
            {
                carBody.AddRelativeTorque(Vector3.up * currTurn * turnStrength);
            }
            else if(currTurn < 0)
            {
                carBody.AddRelativeTorque(Vector3.up * currTurn * turnStrength);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to rethink your game's logic. Raycasts are computationally expensive. You are firing two on the `FixedUpdate()`. Then you have have a for loop inside that update, which is generally a bad idea.

If you really need to know the distance to the ground fire a raycast on the `Update()` instead.

Comment: Hello, thank`s for answer. I past the second Raycast into Update. It help a little, but jerks still stayed, but no so big. I also think so - about the logic, but how -I didn`t know. Can you help me?

Comment: @Roman it is pretty hard to change the logic of what your doing, you would need to narrow down what your doing in detail. Perhaps on another question. The more you narrow down a question the easier it is for people to help you. Also, you might want to only fire the Raycast if you are moving or pressing a key.